# Jquery - Passing a function to the filter function, with two parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, filter

In Jquery functions such as filter and not, you can pass a function which passes two parameters. I'm reading a book and it says that the first parameter is the index of the current element, while the second parameters is the current element. I'm confused. What is the difference between using the second parameter and using the this key word. Doesn't the this keyword also point to the current element? Does this point to the current element, as a reference, while the element parameter is the element. Which one do I use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
array.filter(function(currentValue, index, arr), thisValue)
```

currentValue(Required)- The value of the current element

index(Optional)- The array index of the current element

arr(Optional)- The array object the current element belongs to

thisValue(Optional)- A value to be passed to the function to be used as its "this" value.
If this parameter is empty, the value "undefined" will be passed as its "this" value

Comment: OP is not asking about `Array.prototype.filter()` but about `$.fn.filter`

Answer (score 0):

Arrow functions retain the `this` keyword from the outer scope.

Regular functions do get an updated `this`.

Examples in the snippet.

```js
var $body = $(document.body);

console.log("Testing arrow functions");
$body.each((idx, el) => {
  console.log(el === this);
  });

console.log("Testing regular functions");

$body.each(function(idx, el) {
  console.log(el === this);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```